# How to stop validation on constraint failure in Symfony2

Tags: php, validation, symfony, chain

If I have many validators against my entity, can I somehow specify one that it stops the rest if it fails? IE: there's no point checking Permissions if it fails NotBlank.

Alternatively, if its not built in, perhaps theres a way to signal the graph walker to stop, and I can put in a validator that checks for prior failures and stops propagation through the graph.

Comment: I would appreciate knowing the answer to this as well. For me, in the NotBlank case, HTML5 prevents the user from seeing unnecessary errors, but I expect I will soon run into a more complex case where I have two or more validators besides NotBlank.

Comment: Does this look promising? https://gist.github.com/rybakit/4705749 You're able to chain validators and have a flag `$stopOnError`. You probably need to change it a bit, because it's written for Symfony2.1.

Comment: Refs https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/20017

Answer (score 3):

Despite this being quite old, as of 5.1 there is a way to do this by using the [`Sequentially`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Sequentially.html) constraint.

> This constraint allows you to apply a set of rules that should be
> validated step-by-step, allowing to interrupt the validation once the
> first violation is raised.

You would just pass an array of the constraints to validate:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Sequentially({ @Assert\NotBlank(), @Permissions() })
 */
```

Answer (score -1):

If you set the validation in `./app/config/validation.yml` then SF2 will validate as the order of validations in the file. Once a validation is failed, it ignore the others.