# Symfony2 : Validation Halt on First Error

Tags: php, validation, symfony

It seems the `$validator->validate( $class );` of the Symfony2 [Validation Service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html) runs through all the validation checks before if returns the `$error` class. This is normally OK but I'm looking for `halt_on_failure` functionality because once a particular property fails it triggers a `PHP` error on a proceeding Validation check.

It's fairly well documented in Symfony-1 that there was a `halt_on_error` but I'm not sure how this works in Symfony2. I've found references to it but no examples.

Here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135345/how-to-stop-validation-on-constraint-failure-in-symfony2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Found Two solutions for this problem.

1. **Using Groups**. [Richard Miller](http://richardmiller.co.uk/2012/06/15/symfony2-using-validation-groups/)
   wrote a nice summary of SF2 Validation with Groups. Essentially,
   what I did was labelled the initial validation steps with
   `Step1` and left the rest of the steps alone. You then make the request to the Validator service like this:

   $this->validator->validate($class, array('step1', 'Default'));
2. **Additional IF Statements**. In my situation, I was using an API to validate so I wanted to make sure the inputs were accurate so I didn't waste an API request. IF statements can be used to cut off the API request and `return false`.

### What I Choose to do and why

I choose to go with step 2. While, step 1 was probably better use of the validation technology, I wasn't wild about the additional group parameters that needed to be added. It was a code maintenance liability. It seems in Symfony2.2, there will be a `halt_on_error` feature and this solution should be updated at that time.