# Stop validation on first error flag in Symfony2?

Tags: validation, symfony-2.2

I'm searching for informations if there is some kind of flag/option that force symfony2 validation stop on first error in validation chain. For example I have three validators on my `email` field:

```yaml
email:
    - NotBlank: { groups: [ send_activation_email ] }
    - Length: { min: 6, max: 80, charset: UTF-8, groups: [ send_activation_email ] }
    - Email: { groups: [ send_activation_email ] }
```

I want to stop validation after first error. How can I achieve that? I read similar questions:

[Symfony2 : Validation Halt on First Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568922/symfony2-validation-halt-on-first-error)

[How to stop validation on constraint failure in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135345/how-to-stop-validation-on-constraint-failure-in-symfony2)

[Symfony-2 gives more than one validation error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627337/symfony-2-gives-more-than-one-validation-error-message)

Last one is quite good but is there any way to do this without using validation groups every time, when there are more than one validator? I read somewhere that in Symfony 2.2 there will be a flag or option for this, but I have 2.2.1 version and can't find such option.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Chain` validator for that purpose: https://gist.github.com/rybakit/4705749

Here's an example in plain PHP:

```php
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Date;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Type;
use Acme\Validator\Constraints\Chain;

$constraint = new Chain([new Type('string'), new Date()]);
```

In XML:

```xml
<!-- src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/validation.xml -->

<class name="Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\AcmeEntity">
    <property name="date">
        <constraint name="Acme\Validator\Constraints\Chain">
            <option name="constraints">
                <constraint name="Type">
                    <option name="type">string</option>
                </constraint>
                <constraint name="Date" />
            </option>
        </constraint>
    </property>
</class>
```

But be aware that if you want to have nested `Chain` constraints, like:

```php
<?php

$constraint = new Chain([
    new Callback(...),
    new Chain([new Type('string'), new Date()]),
]);
```

you have to override the `validator.validator_factory` symfony service to fix the issue with handling nested constraints in the current implementation: https://github.com/symfony/Validator/blob/fc0650c1825c842f9dcc4819a2eaff9922a07e7c/ConstraintValidatorFactory.php#L48.

See the `NoCacheConstraintValidatorFactory.php` file from the gist to get an idea how it could be solved.

Answer (score 0):

As of Symfony 2.3 you can do this using [Group Sequences](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#group-sequence) (though form support for group sequences might be spotty).

Comment: So if I want to stop validation after every error I should create as many group sequences as there is maximum number of validators on a single form field? For example I have two fileds, first with 2 validators and second with five. So to stop on every error I must create five group sequences?

Comment: As I understand it, yes. Though if I were you I'd check on group sequence validation support with forms. I'm sure version 2.2.1 doesn't support them.