# Group Sequence feature not working in Symfony2

Tags: php, validation, symfony, symfony-2.8

I have a `Profile` entity with an `email` field and I'm trying to validate it using Symfony Validator. I'm trying this using the [GroupSequence](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/validation/sequence_provider.html) feature because one of my constraints is fairly expensive from a computation point-of-view.

Basically, I want a **valid** email address and the **domain should not be blacklisted** (a custom constraint that uses an internal list of domains). The last constraint I want to be applied only if the email is valid, so I'm using the *group sequence*, but it's not working as expected.

I'm using Symfony 2.8.2 and I have the following *validation.yml* file:

```
Namespace\Entities\Profile:
    group_sequence:
        - Profile
        - common
        - email.strict
    properties:
        email:
            - Email: { groups: [common, email.strict] }
            - Namespace\ProfileBundle\Validators\Constraints\EmailNotBlacklisted: { groups: [email.strict] }
```

The validation is done like this:

```
$profile = new Profile();
$profile->setEmail('blacklisted.com');
$errors = $this->validator->validate($profile, array('common', 'email.strict'));
```

Given that `blacklisted.com` is an invalid value, I'm expecting the `Email` constraint to fail and therefore it should never reach the `EmailNotBlacklisted` constraint.

However, `$errors` contains errors from both constraints.

**What am I doing wrong in this usage of `group_sequence` feature?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop validation on first error flag in Symfony2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359928/stop-validation-on-first-error-flag-in-symfony2)

Comment: @NDM I want to use the **GroupSequence** feature from Symfony and I don't want to implement something custom since they said in documentation that this should work